# quote character problem while sending XML data in action script 3

Tags: php, xml, flash, actionscript-3

I use following method to send `XML` data to server but it seems quote characters disappears in attributes and `php` can't detect attributes! :'(

```
public function sendXml(url:String, xmlData:String){
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    req.contentType = "text/xml";
    req.data = xmlData;
    req.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
    navigateToURL(req);
}
```

I use following url: `http://localhost/mysite/index.php?xml=` and data append to end of url.

Any sample code will be great, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you setting the XML as a URL param, be sure to encode the string before request.

Following should do:

```
trace(escape(str));
```

Comment: i put it in `req.data = escape(xmlData);` but doesn't work! :'(